# How to use hook in createSlice of react redux

Tags: redux, react-hooks, local-storage, redux-toolkit

How to use hooks to save data in localStorage in createSlice  of react @reduxjs/toolkit
When ever I change the theme I want to save the data in localStorage. I know this can done directly with js code with I am having issue with useLocalStorage hook.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import useLocalStorage from "../hooks/useLocalStorage";

const initialState = {
    theme: true
}

const [settings, setSettings] = useLocalStorage("settings", initialState);


export const settingsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "theme",
    initialState: { value: initialState },
    reducers: {
        setSettings: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        },
        toggleTheme: (state) => {
            const temp = { ...state.value, theme: !state.value.theme };

            //save in localStorage
            setSettings(temp);

            state.value = temp;
        },
    },
});

export const { toggleTheme } = settingsSlice.actions;

export default settingsSlice.reducer;
```

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
        try {
            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    const setValue = (value) => {
        try {
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return [storedValue, setValue];
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

[image]

I tried to call the hook before updating my data but I got error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple things:

1. Reducers have to be pure functions. That means no side effects like reading data from anywhere except from `store` and `action` and no writing data anywhere, too. You are not allowed to use localStorage from a reducer.
2. Hooks can only be called from React components - not any function outside of one. The good thing is that if you do not want a component-local state "synced" with your local store (here you don't), all your code here boils down to `window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));` - you don't need the `useState` stuff here.
3. Most people just use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save a copy of state to localStorage and restore that. It is highly configurable, so you can also only save a portion of it.
4. If you want to do it by hand, you need to use *some* kind of middleware (since that is where side effects belong in Redux) - I would recommend using the [listener middleware of RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) to look for store changes and saving in a listener middleware effect.

Comment: So now I have moved the data saving part to App.js file which is working the way i wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** : I have moved the data saving part to App.js file, where i can listem for changes in settings and call the useLocalStorage hook

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import routes from "./routes";
import useLocalStorage from "./hooks/useLocalStorage";

const App = () => {
    const content = useRoutes(routes);
    const [, setSettings] = useLocalStorage("settings", {});

    const settings = useSelector(state => state.settings.value);


    useEffect(() => {
        setSettings(settings);
    }, [settings])


    return <>
        {content}
    </>
}


export default App
```